# where can i get latest solana database snapshot?

Tags: validator, node

Now, i'm trying to launch a solana mainnet validator node, and could anyone tell me where can i download the lastest database snaphot to speed up my node syncing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [solana-snapshot-finder](https://github.com/c29r3/solana-snapshot-finder). It will find the fastest RPC node for you and download the snapshot.

Comment: Thanks Serban, but after trying solana-snapshot-finder, which told me it cannot find any valid node to download...

Comment: I tried it myself just now and it worked. Check the error in detail, maybe you need to increase the max_latency. You can ask for help on the solana discord, in the #validator-support channel, this is a widely used tool.

Comment: Just tried again, it worked now, thank you very much